# Get distinct path list ordered by date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data that looks like this:

| invoice | dept | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Xfer Bills | 2022-03-05 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-07-15 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-07-29 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-09-16 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-11-25 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-12-30 |
| 12345 | Government | 2024-02-03 |

What I am trying to get back is the following:

| invoice | dept | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Xfer Bills | 2022-03-05 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-07-15 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-07-29 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-09-16 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-11-25 |

I was thinking of trying to do a Lead or Lag and see if the next/previous had changed. I am trying to get a path of an invoice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG`  within a CTE to compare each row's department `dept` with the department of the preceding row for the same invoice, ordered by date. You can see that I created a new column `PrevDept` to hold the value of the department from the previous row.

So, I select the rows where `PrevDept` is either `NULL`  or different from the current `dept` are selected, (excluding the ones  of the same department and leaving only the first occurrence in each series of consecutive rows) :

```
CREATE TABLE InvoiceData (
    invoice INT,
    dept VARCHAR(50),
    [date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO InvoiceData (invoice, dept, date)
VALUES
(12345, 'Xfer Bills', '2022-03-05'),
(12345, 'Vendor Mgmt', '2023-07-15'),
(12345, 'Government', '2023-07-29'),
(12345, 'Vendor Mgmt', '2023-09-16'),
(12345, 'Government', '2023-11-25'),
(12345, 'Government', '2023-12-30'),
(12345, 'Government', '2024-02-03');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        invoice,
        dept,
        date,
        LAG(dept, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY invoice ORDER BY [date]) AS PrevDept
    FROM InvoiceData
)
SELECT
    invoice,
    dept,
    [date]
FROM CTE
WHERE PrevDept IS NULL OR PrevDept <> dept;
```

| invoice | dept | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Xfer Bills | 2022-03-05 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-07-15 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-07-29 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-09-16 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-11-25 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XAvoqBB9)

Comment: It's not bad to write a little explanation, not just code :)

Comment: @siggemannen explanation added

Comment: @DaleK explanation added

Answer (score 2):

In  the CTE the `CASE WHEN` check the dept name with the previous (`LAG`) and marks changes. it also marks the first row of the invoice, which has the `LAG` of `NULL` so you can get all unique departments,

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (
  [invoice] INTEGER,
  [dept] VARCHAR(11),
  [date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO invoice
  (invoice, dept, [date])
VALUES
  ('12345', 'Xfer Bills', '2022-03-05'),
  ('12345', 'Vendor Mgmt', '2023-07-15'),
  ('12345', 'Government', '2023-07-29'),
  ('12345', 'Vendor Mgmt', '2023-09-16'),
  ('12345', 'Government', '2023-11-25'),
  ('12345', 'Government', '2023-12-30'),
  ('12345', 'Government', '2024-02-03');
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT
invoice, dept, date
  , CASE WHEN dept <> LAG(dept) OVER( PARTITION By invoice ORDER By date )
  OR LAG(dept) OVER( PARTITION By invoice ORDER By "date" ) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_valid
FROM invoice)
SELECT invoice, dept, date FROM CTE WHERE is_valid = 1
```

| invoice | dept | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Xfer Bills | 2022-03-05 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-07-15 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-07-29 |
| 12345 | Vendor Mgmt | 2023-09-16 |
| 12345 | Government | 2023-11-25 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7mthtWUT)